# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘R.utils’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports): undefined exports: .Last.lib [R with Windows]

Tags: r, gzip, gunzip

When I run `library(R.utils)`, following errors pop up:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘R.utils’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports):
 undefined exports: .Last.lib
In addition: Warning message:
S3 methods ‘isOpen.default’, ‘inherits.default’, ‘parse.default’, ‘cat.default’......
```

Does anyone know how to solve it? I am running R over Windows system.

Additional Info:

```
R version: 4.0.5
os Windows 10 x64
R.utils version: 2.10.1
```

Comment: What gets returned when you run `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: What version of R are you running and what version of `R.utils` is installed?

Comment: Please don't paste the output in the comments - edit your question with that information instead.

Comment: R.utils version: 2.10.1

Comment: If you update R to v4.1, are you still experiencing this error?

Comment: Hooray! Updating R to latest version (4.1) helped! Thanks! Although I don't understand why everything is working fine on my Mac system even with older R version (3.6.1).